# How can I toggle between two images as my body's background?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a button that changes the background of my HTML page. Sadly everything I've tried has not been successful, my function just doesn't do anything on click. I tried a few things that others have posted here but none of them worked.

```js
function night() {
  let element = document.body;
  if (element.src.match('image/night.jfif')) {
    element.src = "image/day.jpg";
    console.log("day")
  } else {
    body.style.backgroundimage = "url('image/night.jfif')";
    console.log("night")
  }
}
```

```html
<body style="background-image:url('image/Day.jpg')">
  <button onclick="night()"> Theme </button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function night() {
      if (currentImage === 'image1.jpg') {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url("image2.jpg")';
        currentImage = 'image2.jpg';
      } else {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url("image1.jpg")';
        currentImage = 'image1.jpg';
      }
    }
```

Try this. It might help

Answer (score 0):

This'll do it.

```js
var backimg = 0;

function night(){
  backimg = 1-backimg;
  let b = 'image/Day.jpg';
  if (backimg == 1){
        b = 'image/night.jfif';
  }
    
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+b+"')";
  
}
```

```html
<body style="background-image:url('image/Day.jpg')">
  <button onclick="night()"> Theme </button>
</body>
```